# Why is Jetty hanging when I try to start it in debug mode?

Tags: java, testing, jetty, wicket

My problem is that when I try to launch Start.java in debug mode, Jetty hangs. Here is my Start.java file, taken from the [Wicket quickstart page](http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html)

```
Server server = new Server();
SocketConnector connector = new SocketConnector();

// Set some timeout options to make debugging easier.
connector.setMaxIdleTime(1000 * 60 * 60);
.....
try {
    System.out.println(">>> STARTING EMBEDDED JETTY SERVER, PRESS ANY KEY TO STOP");
    server.start();
    System.in.read();
    System.out.println(">>> STOPPING EMBEDDED JETTY SERVER");
    // while (System.in.available() == 0) {
    //   Thread.sleep(5000);
    // }
    server.stop();
    server.join();
} catch (Exception e) {
.....
}
```

When I try to reach http://localhost:8080, I get:

> HTTP ERROR: 503
>
> Problem accessing / Reason:
>
> SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE

There are no error logs. What's wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: does it work in normal (not debug) mode? What Jetty version (the dependecy from the pom) are you using? What debugger are you using?

Comment: also normal mode gives the same result, jetty version : 6.1.25. Debugger is standart IntelliJ debugger.

Comment: Are you sure that all threads are running correctly. In debugging mode there is often an "auto-halt-on-exception" which may result in one or more threads being halted by the debugger whereas others are running at the same time.

Comment: @Altug: strange, just last week i created a new wicket project using the artefact and it is running fine, also in the idea debugger. Is there any initialisation going on in your WicketApplication class? Is it even getting till there?

Comment: @bert - simple wicket quickstart app works fine with Start.java  but my application which includes Spring + Hibernate + Wicket doesn't work with that Start.java, Also it is very strange that there is no log anywhere.

Comment: @Altug wierd. I have another project that uses JPA/Hibernate and Spring. I will check it this evening and see if i can start it in debugger. Did you try in Debugger to see where it hangs / stops?

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably caused by your IDEA debugging options. At the breakpoints section for each breakpoint there is a suspend all / thread option. If you have stopped at a breakpoint which suspended all threads Jetty will not answer requests (since it has been suspended). Change the breakpoint to "thread".

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer, I wish I can give you a bounty. This saved my day and my sanity.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, Wicket hung on startup. After activating the debug log in log4j, I found out it hangs while generating or read a random from the underlying OS.

Try this: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Connectors+slow+to+startup

Comment: Hi Tim, but other small wicket application can work in the same mode without hanging. Also I will try your solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Altug: Give it try and let me know if it helps. I think the random that I talked about is only obtained if you use SSL/https...